# OBDII Codes P0304 and P0430

Tags: cel, lexus, p0430

On a 2005 Lexus RX330:

<kbd>P0304</kbd> Cylinder #4 misfire.

What is the cause and is it a big job to fix?

<kbd>P0430</kbd> Catalyst system efficiency below threshold - Bank 2.

Is this a big job?

Is it OK to run the car without fixing them?

Comment: They were changed in April,2014 so about 10,000 km.  All are irredium.

Comment: no. The problem has been solved by changing one coil and cat repair.

Answer (score 2):

The OP resolved this issue as per his [comment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12929/obdii-codes-p0304-and-p0430#comment17054_12929):

> The problem has been solved by changing one coil and cat repair.

So the reason for the misfire was a bad coil, while the catalytic converter had to be "repaired", possibly replaced due to clogging.